# Passing Local Image To a Class Component - React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a `HomeCard` Function Component which Looks Like this:

```js
import React from "react";

const HomeCard = (props) => {
  

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source={props.image} style={styles.image} />
    </View>
  );
};
export default HomeCard;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
//Some Style
});
```

I then Import this component to my `HomePage`

In my `HomePage` I have an Array with
static data for the cards.
Then I map this Array and assign the props to the `HomeCard` and render it on the screen.

I also made the `HomeCard` Clickable to navigate and let's say ***Open*** the card and display its properties on Another Screen

Here is the Home Screen

```js
import React from "react";
//More Imports

export default class Home extends React.Component {
 //Some Code
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      <ScrollView>
      //Some Code
          <View style={styles.barContainer}>
            <ScrollViewWithCards navigation={this.props.navigation} />
          </View>
      
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
//Some Style
});

const cards = [
  {
    day: "3",
    month: "Jan",
    numberOfPeople: "4",
    time: "17:00-18:00",
    title: "Dance Class",
    image: require("../../../assets/images/image1.jpeg"),
  },
  //More Cards...
];

const ScrollViewWithCards = (props) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {cards.map((card, index) => (
        <View key={index} style={styles.cardContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() =>
              props.navigation.navigate("ThisLesson", {
                image: card.image,
                day: card.day,
                month: card.month,
                time: card.time,
                title: card.title,
                numberOfPeople: card.numberOfPeople,
              })
            }
          >
            <HomeCard
              image={card.image}
              day={card.day}
              month={card.month}
              time={card.time}
              title={card.title}
              numberOfPeople={card.numberOfPeople}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

### The Problem Is:

When I Move to the Screen when clicking the card all the props are pass down fine just the image doesn't

```js
import React from "react";

export default class ThisLesson extends React.Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);

    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.topImageContainer}>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={this.props.image} />
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
//More Style
  image: {
    width: "100%",
    height: 277,
  },
});
```

If I `console.log` the Screen props this Is My Result:

```
"params": Object {
      "day": "3",
      "image": 21,
      "month": "Jan",
      "numberOfPeople": "4",
      "time": "17:00-18:00",
      "title": "Dance Class",
    },
```

The Image `source` becomes a number and nothing is displayed, Any Idea what happening?

Comment: Try passing that image as a base64 string.

Comment: can you refer me to a guide/docs to do that?, note: I'm using expo

Comment: or, you can just send the path of the image to the child component as a prop

Comment: Haven't I already done so in the `ScrollViewWithCards`?

Comment: just try passing the relative pathname without the require() as a prop as its just a string.

Comment: already tried, doesn't work, you can't do `source={require(this.props.image}`